# Jquery not looping function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to develop jquery plugin,I have stuck with my function on my function call my plugging repeat same value on elements.I do expect replace all values of my page,respectively

```
    ( function ($) {

    $.fn.siPrifixx = function (value, options) {


        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maxDigits: 8,
            seperator: true,
            decimal: 1,
            popUp: true,
            index: "tool tip message"
        }, options);

        console.log(settings.index);

        $(this).addClass('tooltip', 'test');
        $(this).tooltipster({
            theme: 'tooltipster-default',
            functionInit: function () {
                return value
            }
        })

        // $('.tooltip').prop(settings.index, value);

        var number = value;

        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            var parts = value.split(",");
            number = (parseInt(parts.join("")));
        }




            if (typeof number !== 'undefined' && !isNaN(number)) {

                // if the number is alreadey comma seperated convert to number
                var n = settings.decimal
                // 2 decimal places => 100, 3 => 1000, etc
                var decPlace = Math.pow(10, n);

                // Enumerate number abbreviations
                var abbrev = ["K", "M", "B", "T"];
                // Go through the array backwards, so we do the largest first
                for (var i = abbrev.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                    // Convert array index to "1000", "1000000", etc
                    var size = Math.pow(10, (i + 1) * 3);

                    // If the number is bigger or equal do the abbreviation
                    if (size <= number) {
                        // Here, we multiply by decPlaces, round, and then divide by decPlaces.
                        // This gives us nice rounding to a particular decimal place.
                        number = Math.round(number * decPlace / size) / decPlace;

                        // Handle special case where we round up to the next abbreviation
                        if ((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)) {
                            number = 1;
                            i++;
                        }

                        // Add the letter for the abbreviation
                        number += abbrev[i];

                        // We are done... stop

                        break;
                    }


                }

                $(this).html(number)
                console.log(number)
                // return number;
            } else {
                $(this).html(number)
                console.log(number)
                // return value;
            }

    };

}(jQuery));
```

I'm calling function on a loop like this.

```
$.each($(plugin.element).find('.widget-data'), function(index, value)
{
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    var value = data.stats[index];
    $('.widget-data').siPrifixx(value,{
            decimal:2,
            index:index
    });
```

What's the wrong with my code?

Comment: what is `data.stats`?

Comment: it's my ajax response data sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$('.widget-data').siPrifixx`, you're still addressing all elements with the `widget-data` class. Since you're already iterating that set, you shouldn't targets all elements in every iteration. Instead call `$(this).siPrifixx(...);`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with following code:

```
$(plugin.element).find('.widget-data').each(function(index)
{
    var index_current = $(this).data('index');
    var value = data.stats[index_current];
    $(this).siPrifixx(value,{
            decimal:2,
            index:index_current
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no problems with my data , data.stats[index]; will not change,I change $('.widget-data').siPrifixx to $(this).siPrifixx.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!